# Does Marvel Have a Story Where Celestials Come to Earth, or Otherwise Decide the Fate of Mankind?

Tags: marvel, episode-identification

I was reading old Hulk stories at Marvel Unlimited and eventually got to this story from Incredible Hulk #243 from 1962 where Hulk defeats a character called Tyrannus.

In the story, the seeming destruction of Tyrannus is witnessed by a Celestial named Gammenon. He is described as "...the first of the coming Celestials that will determine, in 50 years time, if the human race shall live...or die..."

[image: Incredible Hulk #243 from 1962]

I am not sure if I am understanding the Marvel chronology correctly, but the reference to 1962 in issue #243 (and the previous and subsequent issues available at Marvel Unlimited) make it look like this was originally published that year.

This would mean that 50 years in the future would mean something like 2012.

(On another hand I was not able to find "Thor" magazines from around 1962 at Marvel Unlimited and was not able to check on that statement "see recent issues of Thor" by "Omniscient Al", shown in the image.)

Does Marvel have a story where Celestials come to Earth, or otherwise decide the fate of humankind around 2012?

Comment: Important to remember that comics, *especially* Marvel/DC exist on a sliding calendar. "50 years from now" does not necessarily mean 50  years from the publish date of the issue. Also, 50 years from publish date was 5 years ago, not 2022.

Comment: thanks @phantom42, for correcting that. I can't even count any more, argh;-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That issue of INCREDIBLE HULK (#243) was cover dated January 1980. In THOR issues 283-300 (May 1979 - October 1980), the storyline known as The Celestial Saga was running; this is the story that was referred to in the footnote.

This storyline was, in part, an attempt to wrap up loose ends from Jack Kirby's ETERNALS series, which had been published a couple of years earlier. ETERNALS established that the Celestials, a bunch of (for want of a better expression) giant armored space gods, wandered around the universe uplifting native species to intelligence, and then periodically visiting them to judge how well they're progressing. If I recall correctly, including the first visit, they stop by 5 times; the "5th Host" makes a final call on each uplifted species (and, apparently, usually decides they're a failure and wipes them out). At that point, I think Marvel was due for that last visit in about 50 years (could be mistaken). NOTE: the Celestials apparently created 3 different lifeforms based on the same baseline form: a basic uplifted form (humans); a form with a highly unstable genetic structure (Deviants), and a form with a sort of super-charged genetic structure (Eternals).

During the events of the THOR story, that future visit got bumped up from "50 years from now" to "now". It doesn't go well, but the Asgardians manage to get the Celestials to leave Earth (and humans, Deviants, and Eternals) alone (for good, I think, in theory). Among others things, we find out that Odin had been expecting this, and that this is why the Destroyer (not Drax, but the suit of armor) was created.

So, the "50 years from now" visit was cancelled. And, of course, as others have pointed out, based on the publication of the original ETERNALS series, the visit should have been in 2026; and, of course, given that comic book time passes at a different rate, it's probably only been 8 or 9 years in the Marvel Universe since that story happened (always assuming no significant alterations to continuity from SECRET WARS, when the entire multiverse got smoooshed up and the put back together somehow).

Last: a note on the 1962 thing. It's become normal to refer to series that have been restarted numerous times based on the year when their first issue came out. For that run of THE INCREDIBLE HULK, there are three possible values. The original run of TIH had its first issue published in 1962. It was cancelled after 6 issues. Since the numbering doesn't overlap, some people might choose to lump this second run in with that one. This run of TIH had its first issue published in (I believe) 1968. That was #102 - issues 1-101 were actually TALES TO ASTONISH, and the first issue of that was published around 1959 or so.